# Liferay 6: How to custom display Portals On Successful login

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am using Liferay 6 for development .
I have developed a Custom Login Portlet using Struts2  .

I am able to display my Custom Login page ,  On click of the Submit Button  after  validating the credentials aganist our  MYSQL Databse , please tell me how can i display my 4 other Custom Portlets on entering valid credentials ??

please guide me what is the concept i should refer for this in liferay 
 ( I am using Liferay 6 for development )

Comment: Do you mean 4 other custom portals or portlets?

Comment: SOrry for the confusion i mean 4 other  portlets.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I just wanted to check before answering.

Comment: Can I ask why you're using Strut2 to create your portlet rather than using a subclass of GenericPortlet or Liferay's MVCPortlet classes? This would make these kinds of problems trivial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, the way I would suggest you do this is by:

1. adding the 4 other portlets to your Custom Login page (or add a redirect on successful login, and them to the page you redirect to)
2. Set the permissions of your Custom Portlets to be viewable by only authenticated users. This can be done by removing Guest "View" permissions. This way a non-authenticated user or "Guest" won't see your portlets when the go to the page.

Does this answer your question?

~~ EDIT IN RESPONSE TO COMMENT ~~

Okay, so if you're using Struts, instead of redirecting to a JSP file, you want to redirect to a URL instead. So instead of /view/result.jsp it should be something like http://yoursite.com/page_with_4_portlets_on_it or just a relative URL /page_with_4_portlets_on_it (if the two pages are on the same Navigation level.

HOWEVER:

If you're new to Liferay then I would strongly suggest you use Liferay's inbuilt Portlet architecture using their MVCPortlet class. This will handle all the mappings, and workings that you have to manually write for using Struts. Then you can implement a doPost() method and do a ActionResponse.sendRedirect("/page_with_4_portlets_on_it");

Then this means that when your form action completes Liferay will redirect the user to the page you've specified.

The best place to get started with Liferay 6 portlets, the Liferay way is [here](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/portlet-development).

Comment: Thank you very much for your time to respond .

I am using Liferay with Struts2 . On click of the Submit Button from CUstomLogin.jsp page , it will call execute method of my Action class and validates data against Database .
Please see the struts.xml file .
<action name="helloForm" class="com.Struts2Action">
            <result name="success">/view/result.jsp</result>
        </action>    


Now my question if they are valid credentials , i am showing him a Result.jsp page .

Now my question is 


Inside result.jsp , please tell me how can i display the my 4 Portlets 

Please help .

Comment: How can i add the portlets to a page , to which i am redirecting using Struts Framework .

Comment: I'm afraid you can't use Liferay portlets in that way. The redirect must point to a valid page not a JSP file. If you point to a JSP file, then if it works at all, then all that will happen is that your Custom Login Portlet will change to look like result.jsp. However you can't add portlets to that. You will have to redirect to a Liferay page (not a JSP file) with the portlets on it. Or add all the code for your 4 custom portlets to result.jsp (I don't suggest this).

Comment: Jonny ,you understood my requirement correctly ,  i am new to Liferay , please give me any idea as from Custom Login Portlet how can i redirect to a Liferay page that concists of 4 portlets .

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect what you've said, so I hope this helps you! :-) If you want any further explanations then just comment back and I will edit my answer to reflect them.

Comment: Jonny , thanks for your valuable time and for the clear answer . It helped me a lot . May God bless you .

Comment: My pleasure, I'm glad I was able to help! Feel free to contact me with any further questions you might have. Also check out the Liferay forums as they are a good source of answers and a good place to ask questions as well.